# Quartz.net and Oracle 11 support

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

When using Quartz.net, we are required to support both Sql Server and Oracle. In previous sprints we developed using Sql Server as a datastore, and now I'm trying to make the switch to Oracle. We use Oracle v11.2. I set the provider:

```
<add key="quartz.dataSource.default.provider" value="OracleODP-1123-40" />
```

and I make sure to redirect to exact version of the Oracle driver I intend to use:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.112.3.0" newVersion="4.112.4.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Unfortunately, when Quartz fires up, I get exceptions, seemingly due to the translation of booleans .Net parameters as a boolean db value (I actually debugged this using the Quartz source code). When I debug, and replace the boolean with 0 or 1, then starting up runs fine.

So this makes me wonder, is Oracle 11 still supported in Quartz? Or is there some configuration I overlooked? As an experiment, I also tried to use the ODP managed provider:

```
<add key="quartz.dataSource.default.provider" value="OracleODPManaged-1211-40" />
```

but with the same issues.

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. You need

```
<add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.OracleDelegate, Quartz" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes; Oracle still supported.
but they changed the provider value in the newer version.
so, you have to change provider value to be like this:

```
<add key="quartz.dataSource.default.provider" value="OracleODP" />
```